# cmd bat script that can switch between compatibility admin rights automatic (with .bat)

Tags: cmd.exe

Can you do this action trough command prompt bat file ?

"click Properties. Switch to Compatibility tab. At the bottom of the setting page click "Change settings for all users". Tick "Run this program as Administrator". click OK and save setting."

Comment: Can you use: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers set the value of a String value (name is the path to the exe) to be RUNASADMIN for example.  Or the other option is to launch the process with the __COMPAT_LAYER env variable.  Other option is to install a shim (sdbinst.exe) having created the .sbd file with the Application Compatibility Toolkit.

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/ncMf3dPN/regedit2.png